# Remove accents/diacritics in a string in Angular Probleme with IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer

i try to use String.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "") but i have this error in IE11

ERROR TypeError: L’objet ne gère pas la propriété ou la méthode « normalize »

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552908/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-angular-probleme-with-ie-11/69565931#69565931) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error in IE 11 because [IE doesn't support `normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#browser_compatibility).

You need to use polyfill to support `normalize` in IE 11. You can use module [unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm/) to provide support for `normalize` in IE 11.

1. Run `npm install unorm`.
2. Use `import 'unorm';` at the file where you write the `normalize` function.

Comment: thank you but I did it in the backend in C #